# How to pass a click event from fragment to Container activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I'm implementing a navigation drawer activity in which I have a fragment(consisting of recycler view) in the navigation drawer to dynamically add items to navigation drawer.

I've successfully implemented this concept but am facing a small issue that the navigation drawer does not close when I click on any item in fragment. This is because I'm not able to access DrawerLayout from fragment.

So how do I pass a click listener from my fragment to the activity to close the drawer layout.

Thank you.

Comment: post your code here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a simple solution to do that.
Create an interface

```
public interface ClickInterface {
    public void buttonClicked();
}
```

Then in your activity , implement this interface

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ClickInterface{

   @override
   public void buttonClicked() {
      //do your code here
   }
onCreate() {
       fragment.setInterface(this);
    }
```

Now call this method buttonclicked from fragment class

```
public class ChildFragment extends Fragment {
   ClickInterface interface;

   
   //call this method from activity when activity loads the fragment inside it
   public void setInterface(ClickInterface interface) {
      this.interface = interface;
   }

   public void onClick(View v) {
      interface.buttonClicked();
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I tried implementing this as mentioned in one of the answers but I get a NullPointer Exception on execution.

Comment: can you post the logcat here

Comment: did you call setInterface in oncreate of fragment class?

Comment: `E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.sarthak.news.ItemClickListener.itemCLicked()' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.example.sarthak.news.Frag$1.onClick(Frag.java:61)
                                                                                at com.example.sarthak.news.RecyclerTouchListener.onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerTouchListener.java:41)
                                                                                `

Comment: Yes. I did. This way.
`setItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

                itemClickListener.itemCLicked();`

Comment: i am talking about calling setinterface method

Comment: This is all I did. Can you guide me as to how to call setInterface method. Apology if it is something basic I'm not getting.

Comment: Got it finally. :D Thank you so much. :)

Comment: what did you do ?

Comment: Called the setInterface method. :D

Comment: good, to initialize the value interface instance must call it when u load fragment in on create

Comment: //call this method from activity when activity loads the fragment inside it. Can't you just give an example how to do this?

Comment: @SkSuraj if you see mainactivity it has oncreate where setInterface is called

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with activity from fragment you can use the interface.

For complete info please follow this official link of android developer

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

In onClick(), post an event and subscribe to that event in your activity.

```
//Inside your fragment post the event
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
  EventBus.getDefault().post(SomeEvent)
}
```

And in your activity subscribe to that event

```
@Subscribe
public void onEvent(SomeEvent someEvent){
  //do what you want
}
```

Also, make sure to register and unregister EventBus in onCreate() and onDestroy() respectively in your Activity.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  //...
  if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  //...
  if (EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
      EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }
}
```