# How to send data from activity to fragment when button clicked in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Android Studio. Hello, I'm novice developer.

I want to pass data from activity to fragment. I've already done a lot of searching on this topic.
However, when I searched it, it seems that there was only content passing data while creating Fragment in Activity.

When the **button inside the Fragment is clicked**, the MainActivity transmits and receives Bluetooth data and **sends the received data back to the Fragment** to display it on the screen.

The screen was composed of three tab layouts, but in order to be able to use Bluetooth as it is in all fragments, it was carried out in such a tricky way.

When I click the button, I want to bring the received Bluetooth data **directly** to the screen. What should I do?

[I'm not good at English, so I used Google Translate, and I'm sorry for the inconvenience.]

Comment: may you precise question a bit: Has the bluettoth to do with your problem? If not, you could use actvityViewModel to communicate with the parent activity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a click event from fragment to Container activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573104/how-to-pass-a-click-event-from-fragment-to-container-activity)